# In swift, using final or private class to increase performance is more worth than using struct?

Tags: ios, swift

I read this link. (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27)

I'm wondered if we use final or private class for static dispatch, class is extremely limited to inheritance(I think this is why we use class).

in the first place, Apple recommend struct except two situation in this documentation.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes)

So, can someone come up with an example of what might lead to making a final class instead of struct?

Comment: I think you misunderstood: the second article talks about data storage / models behavior specifically. They don't say anywhere there that they _always_ recommend structures, or you should replace classes with structures. So I think the choice is very clear: are you creating a model / view model? Yes - choose structure (minus 2 points they mention). If No - that article doesn't apply to you.
As for optimization: that sort of optimization is important for "performance sensitive code" (as they said). Most of the time it would be a premature optimization to think of this.

Answer (score 1):

These are two completely separate topics.

1. The first question is one of static vs dynamic dispatch. But this has nothing to do with the `class` vs `struct` question. Instead it is a discussion of the tradeoff the flexibility of dynamic dispatch vs the performance of static dispatch. Admittedly, [that article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) you reference happens to be focusing on the static/dynamic dispatch implementation issues for a `class`. But we have very similar static vs. dynamic dispatch questions for `struct` types within the protocol oriented programming (POP) paradigm, too. (See below.)

   Whether dealing with value types or reference types, it is the exact same dynamic/static dispatch trade-off: Is the performance gain essential and is the loss of flexibility warranted?
2. The second one is about value semantics vs reference semantics. I think the classic “Crusty” [WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408) is a great primer on this topic. And while I think [your link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes) is as excellent, that old WWDC video also has a discussion of [When to use classes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/?time=2530).

In short, Apple advises using value types where appropriate (in order to prevent unintended sharing, mitigate thread-safety synchronization issues, etc.) and that we use static dispatch where essential. But one has largely nothing to do with the other.

---

And before you ask, here is an example of static vs dynamic dispatch with a `struct`.

First, static dispatch:

```swift
protocol P {

}

extension P {
    func f() {
        print("P implementation")
    }
}

struct S: P { 
    func f() {
        print("S implementation")
    }
}

let p: P = S()
p.f()          // “P implementation”
```

And dynamic dispatch:

```swift
protocol P {
    func f()
}

extension P {
    func f() {
        print("P implementation")
    }
}

struct S: P { 
    func f() {
        print("S implementation")
    }
}

let p: P = S()
p.f()          // “S implementation”
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me good session links. what you want to say me is struct with protocol might use dynamic dispatch, so it is meaningless to choose between struct and class?

Comment: I’m suggesting that the choice b/w struct and class is best driven by other considerations (e.g., those outlined in that video I shared or in that second link you shared with us). And I’m suggesting that you simply don’t worry about dynamic vs static dispatch unless you’ve benchmarked it and find that there actually is a performance issue associated with dynamic dispatch. It is exceedingly unusual for the difference to be observable. If you have a concrete example about which you are concerned, post that as a separate question. But I wouldn’t worry about it in the abstract.